# Encode decoded string with Base64String

Tags: c#, encoding

I am learning how to encode and decode string. This is a method to decode chiper text to plain text I found around the web.

```
public static string Decode(string chiperText)
{
    byte[] numArray = Convert.FromBase64String(chiperText);
    byte[] numArray1 = new byte[(int)numArray.Length - 1];
    byte num = (byte)(numArray[0] ^ 188);
    for (int i = 1; i < (int)numArray.Length; i++)
    {
        numArray1[i - 1] = (byte)(numArray[i] ^ 188 ^ num);
    }
    return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(numArray1);
}
```

My problem is I have no idea how to encode to original state. I try this method and it doesn't work.

```
public static string Encode(string plainText)
{
    byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(plainText);

    byte[] results = new byte[(int)bytes.Length - 1];

    byte num = (byte)(bytes[0] ^ 188);
    for (int i = 1; i < bytes.Length; i++)
    {
        results[i - 1] = (byte)(bytes[i] ^ 188 ^ num);
    }

    return Convert.ToBase64String(results);
}
```

Comment: **Do not invent your own crypto**, and do not use crypto invented by random people online.  This is rather insecure.

Comment: @SLaks No, it's not mine. I found it around the web with little changes. I'm just learning not more than that.

Comment: Don't use crypto that other random people invented either.  This crypto is useless.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking for - you've found some random code and wanted to do some exercises with it, but than asking other people to do the exercises for you? Do you need someone to go to casino and play there by any chance - I'm up for it (assuming you paying) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I agree entirely with SLaks comment that the above does not constitute any kind of crypto that you should use, the following procedure will produce the "encrypted" data that you are looking to decrypt:

```
public static string Encode(string plainText)
{
    byte[] numArray = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(plainText);
    byte[] numArray1 = new byte[(int)numArray.Length + 1];
    // Generate a random byte as the seed used
    (new Random()).NextBytes(numArray1);
    byte num = (byte)(numArray1[0] ^ 188);
    numArray1[0] = numArray1[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < (int)numArray.Length; i++)
    {
        numArray1[i + 1] = (byte)(num ^ 188 ^ numArray[i]);
    }
    return Convert.ToBase64String(numArray1);
}
```

Please do not, for a single second, consider using this as a method for 'encrypting' sensitive data.

Comment: Thank you Martin. I learn the logic. It's not for a "real" cryptography. Thank you so much.